# how save value in android to acces other page

Tags: java

in android how we save one value to acces on each page,

for example I am making a login app

and I need user_id to each page for access data from db by this id

or

I am in home page and I want to store user_id ,and I need to access this on any page ,

for example `home=>profile=>` change password,

I want to access `user_id` here to change password

I am trying

```
Intent slideactivity = new Intent(login.this, LoginMenu.class);
    slideactivity.putExtra("uName", n);
```

but When I access it it give empty value on create_password activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Preferences. Please have a read.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also... a previous stackoverflow answer may help you out in this scenario. Have a look here...

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Hope this also helps.